# Is it possible to build a Cordova app for Android that calls a webservice in the background every night at a set time?

Tags: android, cordova, background

I have the following use case:

- Building a Cordova-based mobile app for an Android device
- The app is supposed to fetch data from a server by calling a web-service every day at 4 am
- The device will be turned on (plugged in for battery charge) at 4 am
- No user will be logged in to the app at 4 am, nor the app will be open (on the device screen)
- At 4 am, a call to a server via webservice is made, requesting data to be downloaded
- The server transfers a file and the app stores the data in a database in the device
- Later in the morning, a user login to the app on the device and access the data downloaded at 4 am

Is this scenario possible to implement or are there any restrictions/limitations?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this plugin :

> A Cordova plugin that schedules periodic Android background tasks
> using the JobScheduler.

https://github.com/raphaelmerx/cordova-plugin-scheduler

There might be other background tasks plugins out there, just giving you this direction.